# sparql: randomly select one connection for each node

Tags: random, rdf, sparql, semantic-web

I have the following data:

```
<node:1><urn:connectTo><node:2>
<node:1><urn:connectTo><node:3>
<node:1><urn:connectTo><node:4>
<node:2><urn:connectTo><node:10>
<node:2><urn:connectTo><node:11>
<node:2><urn:connectTo><node:12>
<node:3><urn:connectTo><node:21>
<node:3><urn:connectTo><node:13>
<node:3><urn:connectTo><node:41>
<node:3><urn:connectTo><node:100>
<node:4><urn:connectTo><node:119>
<node:4><urn:connectTo><node:120>
```

As you can see, every node has multiple connections. I want to select one connection randomly for each node.   How can I do this? I've tried the following queries, but none solve the problem:

1. ```sql
   select ?currentNode ?nextNode where {
     ?currentNode ?p ?nextNode
     BIND(RAND() AS ?orderKey)
   }
   ORDER BY ?orderKey
   LIMIT 1
   ```
2. ```sql
   select ?currentNode SAMPLE(?nextNode) as ?nextNode1
   where {
     ?currentNode ?p ?nextNode
   }
   GROUP BY ?currentNode
   ```

   Note: the result gives the first connection of each node but not randomly
3. ```sql
   select ?currentNode ?nextNode (COUNT(?nextNode) AS ?noOfChoices)
   where {
     ?currentNode ?p ?nextNode
     BIND(RAND() AS ?orderKey)
   }
   GROUP BY ?currentNode
   ORDER BY ?orderKey
   OFFSET (RAND()*?noOfChoices)
   LIMIT 1
   ```

Comment: sample is the way to go, surely. Have you tried mixing 1) with 2)? That is, order randomly then group and sample. (We're in the realm of undefined behaviour I suspect)

Comment: Using **sample** on the results of a subquery with **rand** gets the kinds of results you want, at least when using Apache Jena.  However, I *don't* think that the behavior is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**sample** aggregate](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggSample) returns an individual from within a group:

> Sample is a set function which returns an arbitrary value from the
>   multiset passed to it. … For example, given Sample({"a", "b",
>   "c"}), "a", "b", and "c" are all valid return values. Note that
>   Sample() is not required to be deterministic for a given input, the
>   only restriction is that the output value must be present in the input
>   multiset.

This would be a query like:

```sql
prefix node: <node:>
prefix urn: <urn:>

select ?source (sample(?_target) as ?target) where {
  ?source urn:connectTo ?_target
}
group by ?source
```

```
---------------------
| source | target   |
=====================
| node:1 | node:2   |
| node:2 | node:10  |
| node:3 | node:13  |
| node:4 | node:119 |
---------------------
```

Of course, as you note, the implementation just has to return an arbitrary individual.  This could easily be the *same* one each time.  You *could* do some ordering in a subquery and hope to randomize the order of the targets in order to get different results from **sample**, but there's no requirement that the order of results from a subquery is preserved either.  That would look like this:

```sql
prefix node: <node:>
prefix urn: <urn:>

select ?source (sample(?_target) as ?target) where {
  { select ?source ?_target {
      ?source urn:connectTo ?_target
    }
    order by rand() }
}
group by ?source
```

This seems to work with Apache Jena.  Here are results from repeated calls:

```
---------------------
| source | target   |
=====================
| node:1 | node:2   |
| node:2 | node:11  |
| node:3 | node:100 |
| node:4 | node:120 |
---------------------
```

```
---------------------
| source | target   |
=====================
| node:1 | node:3   |
| node:2 | node:11  |
| node:3 | node:13  |
| node:4 | node:120 |
---------------------
```

```
---------------------
| source | target   |
=====================
| node:1 | node:3   |
| node:2 | node:10  |
| node:3 | node:21  |
| node:4 | node:119 |
---------------------
```

```
---------------------
| source | target   |
=====================
| node:1 | node:3   |
| node:2 | node:10  |
| node:3 | node:100 |
| node:4 | node:119 |
---------------------
```

Comment: Hello Joshua, you are the man!!! Your query really helped me. Thank you so much!  Just another general question: is there any way to sample the results based on other kinds of distributions rather than uniform distribution(which is the 'random' we were talking about?). Feels like Sparql doesn't provide the flexibility to do so.

Comment: @daydayup I don't know of one.  It's still a relatively young standard, and the standard doesn't include a whole lot of functions.  However, many implementations provide additional functionality or ways to implement extensions.  You might check the documentation for your implementation.