# randomly take two different objects for one predicate

Tags: random, rdf, sparql

I have an RDF dataset like this:

```
<subject1> <some_predicate> "Value 1" .
<subject1> <some_predicate> "Value 2" .
<subject1> <some_predicate> "Value 3" .
<subject1> <some_predicate> "Value 4" .
<subject1> <some_predicate> "Value 5" .

<subject2> <some_predicate> "Value 6" .
<subject2> <some_predicate> "Value 7" .
<subject2> <some_predicate> "Value 8" .
<subject2> <some_predicate> "Value 9" .
<subject2> <some_predicate> "Value 10" .
```

Now, for each subject I want to have two random values of "some_predicate". They ought to be two **different** ones. So, the expected result would be something like:

```
--------------------------------------------
| subject | random_value_1 | random_value_2 |
============================================
| subject1 | "Value 2"     | "Value 5"      |
| subject2 | "Value 6"     | "Value 7"      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I found this question [sparql: randomly select one connection for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103024/sparql-randomly-select-one-connection-for-each-node) However, the problem there is just to get **one** value, I need **two and different** values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do *just* about the same thing, but it's a bit more complicated.  First select one random value for other the subject.  Then, in an outer query, select one more random value in the same way, but one that's different from the first (you could allow the same by removing the filter):

```sql
select ?subject (sample(?v1) as ?value1) (sample(?v2) as ?value2) {
  { select ?subject ?v1 ?v2 {
      { select ?subject ?v1 {
          ?subject <some_predicate> ?v1
        }
        order by rand() }

      ?subject <some_predicate> ?v2
      filter(!sameTerm(?v1,?v2))
    }
    order by rand()
  }
}
group by ?subject
```

Note that the same caveats apply that applied to the linked question, [sparql: randomly select one connection for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103024/sparql-randomly-select-one-connection-for-each-node);  since the implementation of **sample** isn't specified, it could conceivably give you non-random results.  Here are some sample outputs using Jena's ARQ:

```
---------------------------------------
| subject    | value1     | value2    |
=======================================
| <subject1> | "Value 1"  | "Value 2" |
| <subject2> | "Value 10" | "Value 6" |
---------------------------------------
```

```
--------------------------------------
| subject    | value1    | value2    |
======================================
| <subject1> | "Value 4" | "Value 1" |
| <subject2> | "Value 8" | "Value 6" |
--------------------------------------
```

```
--------------------------------------
| subject    | value1    | value2    |
======================================
| <subject1> | "Value 4" | "Value 3" |
| <subject2> | "Value 6" | "Value 8" |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Only problem is the performance. On my machine and with about 170 000 triples, it taktes about 1 minute for the query to be executed.