# How do I generate a random sample of data in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, random

Is it possible to generate a random sample of triples using SPARQL?
I thought it might be via the SAMPLE function but this returns a single SAMPLE.

My workaround would be to generate a random number to use with the OFFSET keyword and use the LIMIT keyword to return the desired sample size. I'll just hardcode the random number for offset to 200 for ease like so:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?s ?p ?o
} 
OFFSET 200 #random number variable
LIMIT 100
```

Any better suggestions to generate a random sample of 100 data triples from a  SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: It's not quite a solution, but the answer to [sparql: randomly select one connection for each node](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29103024/1281433) may be useful reading.

Answer (score 7):

In SPARQL 1.1 you can try to use

```
 ...} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100
```

But whether this works might depend on the triple store.

Comment: Thanks. It's running but I thought RAND() returned a random number. What does it do in the context of ORDER BY please?

Comment: ps for context It definitely returns different seemingly random data to that returned by a simple OFFSET/LIMIT approach just don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: @Hilary `SELECT { ... } ORDER BY RAND()` does the same thing that `SELECT { ... BIND(RAND() AS ?rand) } ORDER BY ?rand` would.  It generates a random number for each result binding, and then orders the results by that random number.  It's essentially shuffling the results for you.

Comment: OK thanks Joshua. That makes sense. Does the the LIMIT get applied before or after the ORDER BY i.e. will I always get the same random sample using the same LIMIT?

Comment: Would this approach (sorting the data) be efficient for something as large as Wikidata?

Comment: sadly no, while this works it is absolutely not efficient on large datasets

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer may work but is not optimal as the suggested approach may lead to errors on some triple stores (e.g. on [Apache Jena](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-506)).

As pointed out in the ticket and by [@Joshua-Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor) in the comment section above, a better answer is:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 
{
  ...
  BIND(RAND() AS ?sortKey)
} ORDER BY ?sortKey ...
```